# How prove this arithmetic progression cannot have terms of the form $2^m+3^n$ only?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a_{i}\in \mathbb{N}$, $a_{i}\ge 1$, $i=1,2,\ldots,7$ be arbitrary, and such that
$a_{n+1}-a_{n}=d\neq 0,n=1,2,\cdots,6 $.

Then there exists $a_{\ell}$, $\ell=1,2,\ldots,7$, such that
$$a_{\ell}\notin \{x:x=2^m+3^n,\;m,n\in \mathbb{Z},\;m,n\ge 0\}$$

Comment: LaTeX tips: Use `\mathbb{}` for blackboard bold letters, and use `\ldots` for an ellipsis.

Comment: As to the content of your question: it is very unclear how the $a_\ell$ relate to the $a_i$. Are they supposed to be the same numbers?

Comment: I think the question is that if there are $7$ numbers in arithemtic progression, then not all of them can be of the form $2^m + 3^n$.

Comment: is it 7 or 8 numbers ? I mean, does $a_{i-1}$ with $i = 1$ mean that $a_0$ is included in the sequence ?

Comment: then again I believe that $5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19\,\cdots\,$ is such an arithmetic sequence, and all of its elements can be written $2^n + 3^1$ (with $n \ge 1$), right ? which would seem to disprove the hypothesis.

Comment: oh,I have edit : is $7$.

Comment: @lmsteffan: $15$ is not a number of the form $2^m + 3^n$.

Comment: The question is correct and $7$ is tight, because the longest AP in the set of numbers of the form $2^m + 3^n$ ([A004050](http://oeis.org/A004050)) is the 6-term AP $3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13$. (These are $3 = 2^1+3^0$, $5 = 2^2+3^0$ (OR $5 = 2^1+3^1$), $7 = 2^2 + 3^1$, $9 = 2^3 + 3^0$, $11 = 2^3 + 3^1$ (OR $11 = 2^1 + 3^2$), and $13 = 2^2 + 3^2$.

Comment: yes, $7$is tight!.and I see $40 $methods. this is china Olympic Tst competition 2009 problem 6,can see[link]:http://wenku.baidu.com/view/c8f8de030740be1e650e9afe.html,but $7$ I don't prove it.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, thank you for the correction.

Comment: also can see:http://www.docin.com/p-440092216.html

Comment: Sorry for reviving this old question. As there probably are some people like me, who are interested in seeing a proof, but do not read Chinese, is it possible for someone to post an answer - maybe @math110? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A number of the form $2^m + 3^n$ [can only take on $163$ possible values mod $4095$](http://pastebin.com/7s8XUnH9), and in fact there are no arithmetic progressions of length $7$ mod $4095$ in this set.  So $d$ is divisible by $4095$.  But as long as $n \ge 2$, [there are no numbers](http://pastebin.com/B3bSzxVm) of the form $d=(2^w-2^x)+(3^y-3^z)$ with $w \ne x$ and $y \ne z$ which are divisible by $4095$.  The cases $n=0$ and $n=1$ are seemingly more straightforward to handle.

Comment: Hello, This can only take on 163 possible values mod 4095,This I can't open,Thank you

Comment: and follow there are no numbers" can't open too.

Comment: I guess pastebin is blocked for you, try these: http://jdb.home.kg/p1.pl.txt
http://jdb.home.kg/p2.pl.txt